# How to concatenate multiple dimen in android XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, dimensions

I have one dimen

```
 <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

I want plus `fab_margin` , `android:attr/actionBarSize` ?

like this

```
<dimen name="fab_margin_fragment">(@dimen/fab_margin)+(?android:attr/actionBarSize)</dimen>
```

Comment: convert it int .Use programmatic  approach

Comment: In xml dont any solution ?

Comment: No you cannot do it in XML.  XML in its pure form does not support any operations.

Comment: possible <string name="application_name">Chrome @string/first_name</string> .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use programmatic way.

```
int getMargin= (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin)+(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin_fragment);
```